Add objecto to Mixamo model and export animation to fbx file
I'm trying to add a guitar to a mixamo model. Following tutorials on the internet I have had no problems adding the guitar and having it move properly within blender.
The problem is that when trying to export the model to fbx format.
The guitar does not appear, trying to apply the transformations when exporting it appears very small and out of position with respect to the main model, but never with animation.
If in Blender I try to apply all the transformations, the object is deformed, and if I apply them using deltas, I don't get any improvement.
I have tried to bake the animation in different ways, but I can't get it to export to fbx.
I think the problem is with the animation baking, but I'm not sure and I'm stuck at this point.
Could you tell me how to properly add an object to the Mixamo character so that I can export it as an fbx file with animation?
Thanks

There are several "problems" i see with your question. First of all, you ask for a tutorial, not a specific problem. If it is a specific problem, you should provide a blend file, so we know a) how you added your object to your model and b) how you animated it. Both we don't know. Unfortunately this site isn't a site which should provide tutorials, but answer exactly one specific question. So either i would recommend asking on blenderartists.org (which isn't that restrict) or you provide a blend file with your problem so that we don't have to ask for details.

Thanks for the response. I will try to clarify my question.
The steps I followed:

Download an animated mixiamo model (.fbx)
Import the model into blender.
Download an object  from BlenderKit
I followed a YouTube tutorial to add the object to the animation. Basically add a parent to bone to the object.
I export it to a .fbx file

If I import the new file into another Blender project, the animation of the added object has disappeared.
What step or steps am I missing so that the animation is completely exported?
